# about talker.cpp and listener.cpp : Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , i want to test [11. Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) , i installed indigo, and i have a workspace with catkin i have called catkin_ws1 with a package beginner2_tutorials , and now i make 2 files with name talker.cpp and listener.cpp in path : `catkin_ws1/src/beginner2_tutorials/src` and then change CMakeList.txt in path catkin_ws1/beginner2_tutorials  and then i write `$ catkin_make` but at the end i receive `Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed` , and because of this i think when i write `$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker` , i receive this answer :

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/src/beginner2_tutorials
```

so please help me whether i have done this thing true ( for talker and listener.cpp) and
what should i do  for the errors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221951/about-talker.cpp-and-listener.cpp-:-invoking-%22make-cmake_check_build_system%22-failed/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should run catkin_make in root of your workspace (i.e, `/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/`)

Also can you provide your workspace directory tree and contents of your `CMakeList.txt` file?

**UPDATE**

@fatima, as this part tells;

```
add_message_files() directory not found:
      /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/src/beginner2_tutorials/msg
```

it seems like you do not have `msg` directory in `beginner2_tutorials`. You possibly skipped [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv). You can check it for custom messages etc.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
hi Akif, thank you so much for your help , i solved them as you guided me , but another problem occured that i asked again if you could , please help me : http://answers.ros.org/question/222002/hi-i-want-to-install-catkin_make-but-i-have-an-error-so-i-want-to-know-could-i-change-packagexml/

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-05**:
@fatima, if this is the answer to your question, then please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer. Then, other users will look directly to this answer.